# Trouble fetching data from 1 to 1 relationsip Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

I have set up two model with its row in table. And made a single form to fill both tables and it works perfectly

`Tour.php`

```
public function featuredImage()
{
  return $this->hasOne('App\FeaturedImage');
}
```

`tours` table

`id|name|content|featured_status`

`featuredImage.php`

```
public function tour()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Tour');
}
```

`Featured_images` table
`id|tour_id|path|name`

Code in my controller to pass data to view.

```
$tours = Tour::where('featured', 1)->get();
return view('public.pages.index')
        ->withTours($tours);
```

Code in my view

```
@foreach($tours as $featured)
<div class="thumbnail">
   <img src="{{$featured->featuredimage->path}}" alt="{{$featured->featuredImage->name}}">
</div>
<h4>{{$featured-name}}</h4>
@endforeach
```

The trouble is I'm not able to fetch featured images by writing

`{{$featured->featuredimage->path}}`

and the error is

`Trying to get property of non-object`

on the line `{{$featured->featuredimage->path}}`. I have used this method in my previous project and it had worked perfectly but it isn't going well in this one.

I tried replacing `{{$featured->featuredimage->path}}` with `{{$featured->featuredImage->path}}` but didn't worrked out.

Comment: What is `withTours`?

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
{{ $featured->featuredImage()->path }}
```

Also, you're creating a lot of additional queries here. You should use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) to solve N + 1 problem:

```
$tours = Tour::with('featuredImage')->where('featured', 1)->get();
```

And display data with:

```
{{ $featured->featuredImage->path }}
```

Comment: Didn't work out. Now the error is `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne::$path`

Comment: still no luck. Error is `Trying to get property of non-object ` with your suggested method in comment.

Comment: @ZacharyDale are you sure there is featured image for every tour?

Comment: Yes, boss I'm sure. I can get names of the tour in view. And there are 6 rows filled in both tables.

Comment: You have names of the tour, but do you have featured image for every tour? Since it's one-to-one, you should have the same number of rows in both `tours` and `featured_images` tables.